# Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, imageresizer

On Jan 1st. i installed NopCommerce on my hosted website - complete clean installation. NopCommerce uses the ImageReszier component managed via NuGet in Visual studio.

NopCommerce runes with out any problems on my local installation from the same date but i get the following error when i try to run it on my hosted website.

> Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute'

I use ImageResizer version: 4.0.4.934

```
Stack Trace: 
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute' from assembly 'ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +158
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +91
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +438
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) +64
   WebActivator.AssemblyExtensions.GetActivationAttributes(Assembly assembly) +126
   WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods() +220
   WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods() +28
   WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run() +61

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute' from assembly 'ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +613
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +141
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute' from assembly 'ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9923092
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.114.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I ended up by deleting everything and did a clean installation again. Now it's working.

Comment: Hey,  I am also facing the same issue, will you please let me know the exact steps to fix the same, I have tried to clean and all but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may download wrong plugin S3Reader or AzureReader.
If you are using S3 replace nuget package `ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader` with `ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and after deleting everything in the bin folder and rebuilding the solution, it worked for me !!